# Combining 2 dataframes to produce one file of repeating values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .XLSX file with 2 columns.

and . The  Column is storing multiple data links to  and is separate by a semicolon. I need to manipulate this dataset on input and I am having difficultly thinking which best direction to do.

Thinking of replacing the semicolon with a (,) and then packing the data into a dictionary, where the  is the 'key' and the  becomes a list 'value'.

However, I'm not sure this is the most efficient route to take.

```
d = {'<Name>':['FIL9791','FIL9799','FIL4056','FIL4056','FIL4057'],'<Item To Package>':['package_113572195;package_113594355','package_113572197;package_113594357','package_113566689;package_113591417','package_113566688;package_113591416','package_113566690;package_113591418']

df =pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()

sku = df['<Name>']
upc = df['<Item To Package>']

PartToUPC = {}
PartToUPC[sku]=upc
```

Below is how I need the file to look

All skus in Column A and their individual package code in column B

```
FIL9791 | package_113572195

FIL9791 | package_113594355

FIL9799 | package_113572197

FIL9799 | package_113594357
```

etc.

Comment: Have you tried to import the xlsx file directly in pandas with [pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: yes lol. the original xlsx looks like this in the columns. With the <Item To Package> combined. I created d so you all would have a similar dataframe to work with instead of copy paste

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using `.explode()` after splitting the columns into a list of two values.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
d = {'<Name>':['FIL9791','FIL9799','FIL4056','FIL4056','FIL4057'],'<Item To Package>':['package_113572195;package_113594355','package_113572197;package_113594357','package_113566689;package_113591417','package_113566688;package_113591416','package_113566690;package_113591418']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['<Item To Package>'] = df['<Item To Package>'].str.split(';') 
df = df.explode('<Item To Package>')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    <Name>  <Item To Package>
0  FIL9791  package_113572195
0  FIL9791  package_113594355
1  FIL9799  package_113572197
1  FIL9799  package_113594357
2  FIL4056  package_113566689
2  FIL4056  package_113591417
3  FIL4056  package_113566688
3  FIL4056  package_113591416
4  FIL4057  package_113566690
4  FIL4057  package_113591418
```

Keep in mind `explode()` keeps the original index for the column you applied. So if you wish to reset the index because you don't need them to match the original one. You can add:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    <Name>  <Item To Package>
0  FIL9791  package_113572195
1  FIL9791  package_113594355
2  FIL9799  package_113572197
3  FIL9799  package_113594357
4  FIL4056  package_113566689
5  FIL4056  package_113591417
6  FIL4056  package_113566688
7  FIL4056  package_113591416
8  FIL4057  package_113566690
9  FIL4057  package_113591418
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is what you need

```
d = {'<Name>':['FIL9791','FIL9799','FIL4056','FIL4056','FIL4057'],'<Item To Package>':['package_113572195;package_113594355','package_113572197;package_113594357','package_113566689;package_113591417','package_113566688;package_113591416','package_113566690;package_113591418']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["<Item To Package>"].str.split(';').tolist(), index=df["<Name>"]).stack()
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, '<Name>'])
new_df.columns = ['<Name>', '<Item To Package>']
```